# How to verify an email address before creating the account

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

In my app I want to verify the email address of a user before the account get created/logged in. User will enter an email and click 'Next' then a verification email will be sent. After verifying the email, a page to enter user information (name, phone, etc.) and password. Then on clicking 'Sign UP' will create the account on firebase.

But currently I am using email verification method provided by firebase which creates account and login user before account get verified. Is there any method in flutter to verify an email address by just providing the email address without creating account. Verification can be link based or OTP based. Can anyone help with a solution?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with firebase. You need to use other SMTP like send grid.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth), which combines signing in with email verification. Then once the user is signed in you can shows them a screen for the additional information, and [update the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#update_a_users_profile).

Comment: I can't find 'Email link (passwordless sign-in)' method in the Sign-in method section

Comment: It's under the `Email/Password` provider in the console.