# Is it possible to create a user account in Firebase, only if the email verification is successful?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

Normally, the email verification has been sent to the user after creating the account using `UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword( email: email, password: password, );` in Flutter.

I want to know: is it possible to create a user account in Firebase ,only if the verification is successful?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible the way you are describing it.  Once you run `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, that account is created.

What you can do instead is write some code using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to periodically [delete the accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) that were never verified after they have been unverified for some amount of time.  Perhaps you could use a [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?gen=2nd) to run this sort of process daily.  You shouldn't depend on running this logic in the client app since you have no guarantee that it will continue to run after the account is created.

Also consider using an [email link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth) to create the user account, as you can bundle the creation of the account with email verification in one call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible.

```
Future<void> registerUser(String email, String password) async {
  try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

    // Send email verification
    await userCredential.user.sendEmailVerification();

    // Check if the email is verified before allowing further actions
    if (!userCredential.user.emailVerified) {
      // Handle the case where email verification is pending
      // You might log the user out and ask them to verify their email before signing in again
    } else {
      // Continue with your app flow for a verified user
      // For example, you might automatically sign in the user here
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle any registration errors here
    print("Error registering user: $e");
  }
}
```

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68364731/firebase-do-not-create-users-until-email-is-verified) ant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72726170/how-to-verify-an-email-address-before-creating-the-account) also.

Comment: Isn't that going to create the account, *then* send the email, leaving the account created before the email is sent? I think the OP wants to only create the account if verification succeeds, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: when this `UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance
.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);`  statement executes,the user account is creating. After that,if the email is not verified by the user, the account is still on Firebase. I want to verify the email before creating the account on the 'User' tab on the authentication page.

Comment: I don't think that's the way it works.  The account is fully created when the function returns successfully.  It is just in a state where it's unverified until the email link is clicked.

Comment: What if the user stops using the app before the account is deleted?  You will need to arrange to delete the old account on a backend where you control when and how it works.

Comment: Can I delete the created account if the email is not verified?

Comment: Yes, you can. See my answer.